# Rails - use custom routes, instead of passing url params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing

A User has_many accounts, and an Account belongs_to a Role.  A Role can be 'student', 'admin', 'instructor'.

To view instructors, I could do this:

```
  /accounts?filter_by=instructors

  # controller
  role = params[:role]
  @accounts = Account.joins{role}.where{ role.name.eq(role) }
```

What I would like do is this:

```
 /instructors
```

And, create a route for each type of account.  Im struggling a bit figuring out the best way to create these routes.

```
   resources :accounts do
     collection do
       get "instructors", to: "accounts#index", as: "instructors", default: {filter_by: Role.find_by_name('instructor').id}
    end
  end
```

How would I do this in rails 4 routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess this:

```
resources :accounts, path: 'instructors', as: 'instructors', filter_by: 'instructors'
```

or

```
get "/:filter_by", 
  constraints: { filter_by: /instructors|another_type/ }, 
  to: "accounts#index", 
  as: "accounts"
```

Comment: That did it.  Is there a way to DRY it up, or do I need a resource for accounts and then a resource for each type of account I want a named route for?